# DirectorySearcher not searching entire directory

Tags: .net, active-directory

I'm using System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher for traversing Active Directory for users. In most cases, this works fine. The code is pretty much as follows:

```
Ldapconnection conn = CreateConnection(...);
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher searcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher();
searcher.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;

foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll()) {
}
```

For some reason, this doesn't always traverse the tree completely. If I specify the searchroot to point at a missing subtree, it does import that subtree.

Am I missing something?

Comment: When it doesn't work as expected, is the SearchResultCollection returned by the FindAll method count 1000?

Answer (score 2):

Is it stopping at 1000 users? I believe AD is setup by default to only return 1000 objects.

Comment: First, I only got around 150 users. Second attempt around a thousand, actually. So my second attempt might actually be correct, but I hit the limit. Any way to work around that?

Answer (score 1):

If the SearchResultCollection's count is 1000 in the cases that you experience the problematic behavior, try setting the PageSize property on the DirectorySearcher to 1000.

```
Ldapconnection conn = CreateConnection(...); 
DirectorySearcher searcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher();
searcher.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;
searcher.PageSize = 1000;

foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll()) { }
```